# AngularJS - set HTTP header for GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, authorization

May be this is a general issue, which can be available on internet, But what I got is here.

[Adding a custom header to HTTP request using angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598917/adding-a-custom-header-to-http-request-using-angular-js)

So I followed the same, and changed the code to

Setting header

```
 var config = {headers:  {
                'Authorization': 'XXXYYY token="xxxxxxxx", realm="dash-api"',
                "X-Testing" : "testing"
                }
            };
```

The get request call:

```
return $http.get(api.host+'/agn/12/adv/1860/cam?status=1', config).then(function (response) {
                    return {
                        status:"success",
                        data:response.data.data.active
                    };
                }, function (error) {
                    return {
                        status:"error",
                        data:error
                    }
                });
```

As you can see the request are going in method type OPTIONS, and the `Authorization` token is not set in the request.

Please help me in this issue, as I am struggling from two days.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Have you ruled out CORS as being a problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554414/angularjs-disabling-cors

Comment: Pretty sure it's a CORS request. Not sure why `api.host` would even be there if the request was to the same server that hosted the app. It makes perfect sense for the API provider to NOT allow CORS too, since it seems to be doing token authentication over an unsecured channel.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you take a look at the link you refer to, you are getting the same issue as the author and the author of that post did state that it was a CORS issue - the server he was communicating with didn't support CORS, he confirms this in his comment on his own post.

As for why you are getting an OPTIONS request, this is because CORS makes a "pre-flight" request to the server to establish if CORS is going to be supported, before it will make the actual request.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a `OPTIONS` request most probably because you are making a cross origin request (CORS). Firstly your server should support CORS (by responding to OPTIONS request with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set in the response).

If you are making a authenticated cross origin request, you need to set `withCredentials` to `true` when making the request.

```
$http.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
```