# Error 405 & 401 open weather map API Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, openweathermap

trying to call data through openweathermap api
if I call it through 'GET'method.there is

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=' + ApiKey + '&q=London,us',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': ApiKey
    }
}

$http(req)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: which version on angular are you using?

Comment: try    $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=' + ApiKey + '&q=London,us');

Comment: try `$http.get(URL,{header}).then(function(response){}).catch(function(err){})`

Comment: @anand, its 1.6+

Comment: @HimeshSuthar still 401 error

Answer (score 1):

@faisal
I ran into this error today, and after some debugging, I realized that it was because I had `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'HttpRequest';` in my config file. I just disabled CORS for convenience and solved the problem.

This answer is what helped me: [Disable CORS in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554788/6824252)

Comment: Its very old question, I really appreciate your help, let me check thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the params property to encode the search parameters:

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    //url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=' + ApiKey + '&q=London,us',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily',
    params: { appid: ApiKey, q: 'London,us' }
}
```

The problem is likely that the `&q=London,us` is illegal. The comma character needs to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to `q=London%2Cus`. Use the `params` property to properly encode the parameters.

---

## Update

I tested it with my APPID (which I am not going to publish) and it worked.

Here is my [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrFUiztcbkQoI3qK25DA?p=preview) with the APPID removed.

Comment: now it's 401 (Unauthorized) , used generated apikey & used london only

Comment: yes, I already registered and generated a new api but still same issue

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: can you share your code just XXX your appid, do you think its because of localhost?

Comment: ok I updated, as per your code with just 'London', now error is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?appid=ebXXX5&q=London. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405"

Comment: its same, I uploaded at github
https://github.com/faisaljanjua/weatherapp" check dist/js/app.js

Comment: Here is my [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrFUiztcbkQoI3qK25DA?p=preview) with the APPID removed.